# How to UnitTest in VisualStudio 2008 looking up records from a DataSet (created by reading a binary file)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, binaryfiles

I am writing a unit test for how to build retrieval strings from selected records.  I want to initialize my test method so it can get records from the DataSource.  However, my application doesn't use SQL.  It is a desktop C# .NET application that creates a DataTable from binary files.  Should I find some other way besides unit testing to test building the retrieval strings?  The application always creates the DataTable by reading the files.  We don't have a SQL database.  Should I be creating one for testing?  Then how can I test whether the DataSource is created properly if I can't read the files in my unit test?  And how do all the developers who run unit tests get the same file (where to deploy the SQL file and/or the binary files used to create it).

Comment: What do you want to unit test?  The logic that creates the retrieval strings?  Is that logic written against a DataTable?  IDataReader?  The more you can isolate your logic from the data source, the easier it will be to unit test.  Maybe you could even add a representative snippet of code to your question to show the logic that you want to unit test, and, perhaps, another snippet showing how you might propose to unit test it.

Comment: Are you viewing the unit testing problem as twofold:  1. Testing the building of the retrieval strings from records of the DataTable and 2. Testing the reading of the binary file to ensure that the DataTable "view" of it is correct (i.e. do you have your own reader (IDataReader??) that reads the binary data and realizes it as a DataTable?  That could also influence how you unit test.  You would have two "units" that could be tested independently.